# Adding rank to sequel query for leaderboard

Tags: database, postgresql

Hi all I have what seems to be a simple problem (at least in my head) but I have yet to be able to find a solid way to solve this query.

Below is a query I am running to get the current leaderboard for my app. What I'd like to also get back is the items position/rank as well as an attribute like I am with win, loses etc.

```
SELECT "Item"."id",

(SELECT COUNT("Votes"."id") FROM "Votes" WHERE type = 'up' AND "Votes"."LunchId" = "Item"."id" AND "Votes"."scope" = 'regional')::INTEGER AS "wins", 
(SELECT COUNT("Votes"."id") FROM "Votes" WHERE type = 'down' AND "Votes"."LunchId" = "Item"."id" AND "Votes"."scope" = 'regional')::INTEGER AS "loses", 
(SELECT COALESCE((SELECT round( 100.0*sum( CASE WHEN "Votes"."type" = 'up' AND "Votes"."scope" = 'regional' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )/sum(1), 3) FROM "Votes" WHERE "Votes"."LunchId" = "Item"."id" AND "Votes"."scope" = 'regional' ),0))::DECIMAL AS "percent", 
(SELECT count(*) FROM "Lunches" WHERE date("Lunches"."createdAt") = (SELECT date("createdAt") FROM "Lunches" WHERE "Lunches"."id" = "Item"."id") AND "Lunches"."region" = "Item"."region")::INTEGER AS "total"

FROM "Lunches" AS "Item" 

WHERE "Item"."region" = 'east' 
AND "Item"."createdAt" BETWEEN '2015-06-15T011:30:00-04:00' AND '2015-06-15T16:00:00-04:00' 
ORDER BY "percent" DESC, "wins" DESC, "Item"."createdAt" ASC;
```

The reason I want the formatting like this is I want to be able to also easily request it by having an AND "Item"."id" = 40 to it also and find out its rank quickly. Is this doable?

Thanks!

------ UPDATE -------

Here is my tables schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "Lunches" (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    region "enum_Lunches_region" NOT NULL,
    timezone character varying(255),
    description character varying(255),
    "regionWinner" boolean DEFAULT false,
    "nationalWinner" boolean DEFAULT false,
    type character varying(30) DEFAULT 'restaurant'::character varying,
    "createdAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "LocationId" integer,
    "UserId" integer,
    "PhotoId" integer
);

CREATE TABLE "Votes" (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    type "enum_Votes_type",
    scope "enum_Votes_scope" DEFAULT 'regional'::"enum_Votes_scope",
    region "enum_Votes_region" NOT NULL,
    "createdAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "LunchId" integer,
    "UserId" integer,
    "CompetitorId" integer
);
```

Comment: Could you also supply the schema of your db?  
Eg, "CREATE TABLE Lunches ... CREATE TABLE Votes .. INSERT INTO Lunches ... INSERT INTO Votes"

Comment: Which pg version are you using? Also why question is tagged with mysql?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want the `rank()` function, along with some sort of window/partition. Take a look at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-window.html

You might be able to add

```
rank() over (order by percent DESC, wins DESC, item.createdAt ASC)
```

as a column in your query and get what you're looking for.

You might also be able to make your query easier to read with Common Table Expressions; http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html

For instance:

```
WITH vote_summary AS (
select votes.LunchId, sum((type='up')::int) as wins,
       sum((type='down')::int) as losses
  from votes
 where votes.scope = 'regional'
group by votes.LunchId
)
...
```

could save you a whole lot of subselects

Comment: I tried to include the rank in my example but no luck as the wins column is not yet present. Can you explain your example further?